# Android : how to find the "known" WiFi networks?

Tags: android

I saw that some Apps could list networks that I had connected to earlier, but were no longer available right where I was. How does the App get them? I know we can get the list of currently available networks using WiFi Manager's scan function. How to get the list of known networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the docs for `WifiManager`? There's a [`getConfiguredNetworks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) method that looks like what you want.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wm.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you device is rooted you can read the file:

> data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

which contains all known networks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question and later an answer Dec 2022.
On my Samsung with Android 12, Settings>Connections>Wi-Fi
then pick the three vertical dots to get to
Advanced>Manage networks
and they are ALL there.

Enjoy!

Comment: I think the question is asking for how to get it programmatically from within an application that you are writing